# Possible to create/update contacts in JSON format?

Tags: google-shared-contacts

We can retrieve contacts in JSON with the v3 Contacts API -- but can we create or update them in JSON, or do we have to convert to atom format (PITA)?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK it's only possible to retrieve JSON. PUT/POST still requires XML/Atom.

And yes - I agree that full JSON support is definitely needed. The APIs don't seem to receive much love in the last 2 years (see list of open issues here: http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=contact&colspec=API+ID+Type+Status+Priority+Stars+Opened+Summary&cells=tiles)